# how to use websockets for simple game with chat

Tags: node.js, reactjs, websocket

I am building this simple app that uses React and Node, for learning purposes. I want to use websockets for the game and for the chat.
websockets is new to me, and I am wondering if it is recommended to create two different instances for each purpose (game/chat), or should I use the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you are building a simple app with react and node i would try the iosocket and there is tons of videos and similiar project on github where you can check it out to get a glimpse on how it works. Here is even a link to iosocket: https://socket.io/

You can read the documentation and try to implement these bits in your app.

Comment: Just a reminder that socket.io isn't fully implemented via the WebSocket protocol, https://socket.io/docs/v3/index.html

Comment: Yes you are right. When I was new to websockets I personally started with iosocket because It's easy to understand, and personally, I learned how WebSockets work thanks to SocketIO.